# Combine two lists of lists into a dictionary python

Tags: python

I'm not experienced in programming and I have a problem with combining two lists of parsed sentences (=list within list) into a dictionary. I'm using python 2.6.6

I have two lists of sentences, one in English and the other one in German. The sentences correspond: the first sentence in the German list is a translation of the first sentence in the English list etc. 
My goal is to be able to access the English sentence, extract the subject and see whether the German subject corresponds to the English one.

My two lists look like this (simplified):

```
sentences_en = [[u'sid(s1).', u'sentence1', ...], [u'sid(s2).', u'sentence2', ...]]
sentences_de = [['sid(s1).', 'Satz1', ...], ['sid(s2).', 'Satz2', ...]]
```

Each item in the list contains the sentence ID ('sid(s1).'), the actual sentence ('sentenceX' or 'SatzX'), as well as more information on the sentence ('...'). Both lists ('sentences_en', 'sentences_de') contain 10000 items.

I'd like to map the English to the German sentences in a parallel dictionary that looks like this:

```
parallel_dict = {[u'sid(s1).', u'sentence1', ...]:['sid(s1).', 'Satz1', ...], [u'sid(s2).', 'sentence2', ...]:['sid(s2).', 'Satz2', ....]}
```

As I know that I can't have a list as the key, I tried to turn one of the lists into a tuple and use this as the key (I found this solution on Stack Overflow). Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work:

```
parallel_dict = {}
tuple_sentences_en = tuple(sentences_en)
parallel_dict = zip(tuple_sentences_en, sentences_de)
```

When I print parallel_dict, I get the following structure:

```
[([u'sid(s1).', u'sentence1', ...], ['sid(s1).', 'Satz1', ...]), ([u'sid(s2).', u'sentence2', ...], ['sid(s2).', 'Satz2', ...])]
```

It does map the English sentence 1 to the German sentence 1 etc, but it is most certainly not a dictionary - rather a list of tuples.

Does anyone know whether it is even possible to turn this structure into a dictionary with the English sentences as the keys and the German sentences as the values? Or is there a better way to work with parallel data?

I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want two dicts where the key is `sid(sNN)` and the values are the sentences in the corresponding language? (e.g. `dict_en`, `dict_de`). And what exactly do you mean with parallel data?

Comment: Dear Matt, I tried it with two dictionaries with sentence_id = key and the sentence = value. However, I had problems accessing the data afterwards. I want to be able to go through the parsed English sentence and see whether the subject in the sentence is preceded by an article ('the', 'a', 'an'). If this is the case, I'd like to turn to the corresponding German sentence and see whether the German subject is also preceded by an article or not.

Comment: @Matt: With parallel data I mean that I have two sets of data, one in English and one in German, and the first sentence in English corresponds to the first sentence in German (translation), the second to the second etc.  (e.g. sentences_en = [['sid(s1)', 'I am cooking'], ['sid(s2)', 'This is good']...] and sentences_de = [['sid(s1)', 'Ich koche gerade'], ['sid(s2)', 'Das ist gut']...])

Comment: Ok. I'd say you're better off make two dicts (`d_en`, `d_de`) like `{'id1':'s1_en'}` and `{'id1':'s1_de'}`, aftewards: `for id, s_en in d_en: s_de = d_de[id]` (e.g to lookup the corresponding sentences in both languages, simply perform a lookup in the dict where you saved the sentences by their ID. Hope that makes sence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the question:

> whether it is even possible to turn this structure into a dictionary with the English sentences as the keys and the German sentences as the values

The answer is certainly yes. What you need is something like dict comprehension instead of just `zip` (the reason your method does not work is that `zip` returns a list, not a dict).

```
from itertools import izip
sentences_en = [[u'sid(s1).', u'sentence1', 'sentence1_info'], [u'sid(s2).', u'sentence2', 'sentence2_info']]
sentences_de = [['sid(s1).', 'Satz1', 'Staz1_info'], ['sid(s2).', 'Satz2', 'Staz2_info']]
mapping = {s_en[1]: s_de[1] for (s_en ,s_de) in izip(sentences_en, sentences_de)}
```

And `mapping` will be a dict with English sentences as the keys and German sentences as the values, as you wanted it to be:

```
{u'sentence1': 'Satz1', u'sentence2': 'Satz2'}
```

The above output dict `mapping` discards the the ID and additional info on each sentences, which seems to be redundant based on your description of the input lists. In the unlikely case that you really want to retain all of the information in the dict, this will do (and you might have figured it out already):

```
mapping2 = {tuple(s_en): s_de for (s_en ,s_de) in izip(sentences_en, sentences_de)}
print mapping2
```

Output:

```
{(u'sid(s1).', u'sentence1', 'sentence1_info'): ['sid(s1).',
                                                 'Satz1',
                                                 'Staz1_info'],
 (u'sid(s2).', u'sentence2', 'sentence2_info'): ['sid(s2).',
                                                 'Satz2',
                                                 'Staz2_info']}
```

although I think the first `mapping` is closer to what you want.

Comment: Dear @YS-L. The second thing is exactly what I want, as I don't only need the sentence but also all the additional parsing information. And it works for my data! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. You can consider marking this question as solved by accepting an answer if it somehow helps :-)

Answer (score 3):

Since this is for 2.6, use a generator expression for the `dict()` constructor:

```
from itertools import izip

dict((en[0], (en[0], de[0])) for en, de in izip(sentences_en, sentences_de))
```

This uses `izip()` to avoid creating an intermediary list of 10000 items.

The loop unpacks each pair into two lists, from the english and german lists before forming the key-value pair for the output dictionary.

If you can upgrade to Python 2.7 or 3.x, you can use a dict comprehension:

```
{en[0]: (en[0], de[0]) for en, de in izip(sentences_en, sentences_de)}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it always gives me the error:   
    ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it could work with your code but give it a try

```
print {tuple(k):v for k,v in zip(sentences_en, sentences_de)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```
dict(zip(list1, list2))
```